# How to setup bindings between controllers with the new Ember.js router

Tags: ember.js

### Explanation:

Many things have changed with the new Ember.js router. I've migrated most things, but there's one use case that I can't seem to fit into the Ember.js way of doing things.

Say I have an app with some controllers. Some of these controllers belong to the routes in my `App.Router` and some of them don't, namely my `I18nController`. This is a **non-router controller** that makes sure to translate stuff all over the app via a Handlebars helper.

I also have an `App.UserController` that has an `App.User` record as its `content`.

### Problem:

Previously, I was able to setup a binding between `App.I18nController` and `App.UserController` via the rather ugly `localeBinding: 'App.router.userController.content.locale'`, allowing me to read the user's locale at any time when localizing.

However, with the new router, this is no longer possible.

### Question:

My question is: how should I setup this binding using the new router?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the new router there are a couple of different strategies for setting up bindings (dependencies) between controllers. One option is to set `this.controllerFor` in your setupControllers callback in your route defition. Another is to register dependencies for inject prior to app creation. These and a couple of other options are discussed in [this github issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1646). If you follow that thread you'll find code examples for these various strategies. It doesn't seem like a real convention has been established yet but I like the calls like `App.container.injection("controller", "settings", "controller:settingsController")` approach because it is very declarative and clear.

Comment: Yehuda just posted this which is worth mentioning in this relation: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/5becdc4467573f80a5c5dbb51d97c6b9239714a8